# Can I lock a route on IIS?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, swagger

How can I restrict a specific route for IP on IIS?

Example:  the route http://192.168.9.1/myapp/help will be visible only for users on the same LAN.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have the module "IP Security" installed.
Within IIS you can go to the option "IP Address and Domain Restrictions"

Change the access for unspecified clients to Deny. this is within the "Edit Feature Settings". Next make an allow entry for local range, [Click to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYmbu.png).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manage it by using IIS, you need to convert that route into sub application and then use [IP Address and Domain Restrictions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831785%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Steps are as follows:

- Open IIS Manager
- Select that route's folder
- Right click and click "Convert to Application".

Now you can either use IIS Manager to Allow/Deny specific IPs or IP ranges or you can put it into your web.config as follows:

```
<!--Assuming that "myapp" is your main application and your sub application name and path is "help"..-->
<location path="help"> 
   <system.webServer>
       <ipSecurity>
            ...
       </ipSecurity>
   </system.webServer>
</location>
```